# Splunk - Multi-select - Show unique hosts

Tags: splunk

I want to populate the list of hosts in the multiselect input option in Splunk.

`index=someIndexName * host!="notThis*" | stats values(host) as host`

I can see the list of hosts getting populated in Splunk. However, they are not getting populated in multiselect list. It says "populating" and nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this as the populating search

```
index=someIndexName * host!="notThis*" | stats count by host
```

and then use `host` as the `Field for Label` and also the `Field for Value`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="multiselect" token="field1">
      <label>Hosts</label>
      <fieldForLabel>host</fieldForLabel>
      <fieldForValue>host</fieldForValue>
      <search>
        <query>index= someIndexName host!="notThis*"| stats count by host</query>
      </search>
      <choice value="*">All</choice>
      <default>*</default>
      <initialValue>*</initialValue>
      <delimiter> </delimiter>
</input>
```

As Simon Duff also suggested, this works!